# Will doing 301 to url that did 301 the other way around some time earlier would cause trouble?

Tags: redirect, google-search

On a site we have a tag system. Recently we discovered that we have to rename most of the tags and redirect them. It looks like a job for 301 redirect, however some of the tags will be renamed incorrectly (because the process is automatic) and we will return them to their original name at a later time. When that happens we will need to do a redirect back to the original url and probably do a 301 again. Obviously at one time only one of the urls would do a 301 and all of this would happen within the same domain.

For example, we start with **www.example.com/tag/foo**.

Then the automatic name correction would change it to **www.example.com/tag/bar** and do a 301 from the previous address.

The automatic correction would be ok for most tags, but not this one, so we would eventually fix the url back to **www.example.com/tag/foo** and do a 301 yet again.

I tested it (using a site running locally) in Firefox 50 and Chrome 54 and both seem to handle the situation fine (when I redirect to the original address the browser forgets the old 301). Does google (and/or other browsers) also figure this out or am I better of doing 302 and hoping that google changes the address in the index rather than duplicate the pages?

Comment: That will cause a redirect loop which will error or worse hang the users browser (most modern browsers should error). Don't do this. FYI if this is a public site you will loose ranking in google, etc.

Comment: @Liam Even if only one page would do a 301 at that time? When I tested it with Firefox and Chrome it worked, but I only tested it on localhost and browsers might treat that differently.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `301 Moved Permanently` for what you admit in the comments is a `307 Temporary Redirect`. So yes, that causes problems.